# Variable not working when passed into function

Tags: javascript

In short when I define an element to a variable outside of a function using getElementById and try to do something with that variable inside of a function, it wont work. It only works if I explicitly run the getElementById command WITHOUT the variable. What am I missing?

The error is TypeError: nav is null

```js
var nav = document.getElementById("navMenu")

function showMenu() {
  nav.style.right = '0' // doesn't work 
}
```

Comment: `var nav = document.getElementById("navMenu")` is likely executed before the element with the id `navMenu` is in DOM.

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it?  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, and indicate what problem you are observing?

Comment: When ever you ask a question you have to be more precise then just writing does not work. Do you get an error message in the console, and if so what message is it? And create a [mcve].

Comment: Put the variable assignment in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Moving my script tag from the head tag to the bottom of the body tag in the HTML fixed this